# Express not fetching data from postgres database. No errors displayed

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, postman, backend

I found someone with the exact same problem as me, but it had no answers. So I am copy-pasting this guy's question, hope someone can help me:

This is a difficult question for me to ask because I'm not truly sure what the issue is.

I have an Express JS server for routing and Node Postgres (PG) for the pool.

When I either go directly to localhost or use POSTMAN to test the routes there is no response except a simple loading screen. With POSTMAN, it gets stuck like so:

POSTMAN sending request...

Or for localhost it simply stays buffering/loading.

I am following this video on how to deploy a PERN app to Heroku. However, even after cloning the repo and updating all the packages within I cannot fetch data from my database (I am using PostgreSQL). I have updated all the database login information so it's not that.

Below is my code:

Server:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
const pool = require("./db");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

app.get("/todos", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log("route hit"); // this msg gets displayed when i send a req
    const allTodos = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM todo");
    console.log("route hit again"); // this msg does not gets displayed when i send a req
    res.json(todo.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server has started on port 5000");
});
```

Pool

```
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
  user: "postgres",
  password: "postgres",
  host: "localhost",
  port: 5432,
  database: "perntodo"
});

module.exports = pool;
```

All pool information is correct.

I have checked my database and there are active tables and data.

Again, there are no errors displayed so it's super hard for me to diagnose the problem.

Comment: once you get the data, you need to actually [send the response back to the consumer](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res), also see [Response methods](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html#response-methods), you're probably needing `res.json(allTodos)` here

Comment: I edited the question, i forgot to include that part, i actually am sending the response, but my code gets stuck on the await allTodos... line

Answer (score 0):

Try exporting pool like [in the docs](https://node-postgres.com/guides/async-express):

```
module.exports = {
  query: (text, params) => pool.query(text, params),
}
```

Comment: Still the same behaviour :(

Comment: is that on localhost or heroku? well, it would seem the problem is with the pool, the promise doesn't get resolved.. so await hangs.. try moving pool to the app, and query from there, without exporting.. and then maybe try replacing async/await with callback..

Comment: This is on localhost, I will try what you are suggesting now.

Comment: Still can not get it to work, maybe I need to change some config files, give some permission to my user...???

Comment: no idea.. maybe add more error handlers, and try some other options: https://node-postgres.com/api/pool, as well as checking versions and maybe downgrading..